# Probability of Getting a Uniform Distribution from 120 rolls of a 6-sided Dice

Tags: probability

I was thinking about this question today, and couldn't come up with a good way to approach it. Given 120 fair rolls of a 6-sided dice; From all the possible resultant distribution of outcomes, what is the probability that your experimental distribution would be uniform? That is, 20 occurrences of each of the 6 outcomes.

Would this be a valid approach? Segmenting the uniform distribution section by section to find the amount of repeats and then dividing by the total number of possible outcomes?

$$ ({{120}\choose{20}}*{{100}\choose{20}}*{{80}\choose{20}}*{{60}\choose{20}}*{{40}\choose{20}})/6^{120} $$

Comment: Yes! That should work :) I was just about to type that out.

Comment: I just did type that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a multinomial distribution so:

$${120\choose 20,20,20,20,20,20}\frac 1{6^{120}} = \frac{120!}{20!^6\times 6^{120}}\approx 0.0000135\ldots$$

Comment: So OP had a correct answer?